# With Kafka 3.2.3 release, do we still need zookeeper to run kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

KIP-500 has released for a while. https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-500%3A+Replace+ZooKeeper+with+a+Self-Managed+Metadata+Quorum

With the recent kafka 3.2.3 release, do we still need zookeeper to run Kafka?  Kafka Quickstart doc still asks us to start a zookeeper. So I guess the answer is yes?
https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#quickstart

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

Or you can follow documentation here https://github.com/apache/kafka/tree/trunk/raft

But there are several open issues related to it https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-14258?jql=labels%20%3D%20kip-500